# running the code as root on Qt-Creator SDK

Tags: c, linux, qt, qt-creator

I use Qt-Creator 2.5.2 SDK to develop C code on Linux. How is it possible to run the codes as root when it is run from the SDK interface (e.g., ctrl + R)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most simple solution to run Qt-Creator as root

Honestly thats not a trivial task (as long as I tried to do it myself while ago).
Are you sure you really need to run debug under root? If it's about access to some device nodes, may be it's easier to adjust rights on them?

Another solution (keeping QT creator running under user account can be something like)

adjust sudoers (/etc/sudoers)

```
 <user> <machine>= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/gdb
```

then make a wrapper script something like /usr/bin/sudo-gdb:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 sudo gdb $@
```

Then instruct QT Creator use sudo-gdb as debugger.

Comment: Can you suggest how to run it as root _from the SDK interface_?

Comment: there are no straight way to do this, thats' a knows 'issue' however in most cases that's not really needed and can be solved differently

Comment: I tried the sudoers method but prefer to run as my local user to ensure the same window manager and profile settings are used. Therefore, I opted for changing the permissions on the device node. Thanks @evilruff for the tip.

Comment: I could not set/remove breakpoints while debugging or quit debugging using this method. However, I found a better answer on Qt support forum which I will post here.

Answer (score -1):

The following actions were recommended on Qt support forum:

In Qt Creator, add remote Linux device in Options -> Devices. Set its address as localhost and user as root. Create a pair of authentication keys and paste public key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
Then clone Desktop kit in Options -> Kits and set the device for new kit to the device you've created on previous step.

Now, when you start debugging, Qt Creator should automatically connect over ssh to localhost as root, start gdbserver and perform debugging.

It works for running without debugging too.

Perhaps you should set up installation of your program on remote host, but that's a different story and it's done differently for Qmake and QBS.

https://forum.qt.io/post/185983