# how to debug application as root in QT-creator in Ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, qt-creator, libpcap

'm programming application using libpcap. when I debug the application in normal mode, pcap cannot get the network device. it seems that I have to debug the application in root. How can I debug the application in root? I have the root password. I think QT-creator has such an option that can add root for the debugging application,but I don't know how to do it. please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [running the code as root on Qt-Creator SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136035/running-the-code-as-root-on-qt-creator-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can run QtCreator as root. It is disregarded to run GUI applications as root but not disallowed.